# What are Invoke & InvokeAsync methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

What is Invoke methods?

Below here is my `viewcomponent()` method.

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
 ViewBag.SelectedCategory = RouteData?.Values["category"];
return 
View(repository.Products.Select(x=>x.Category).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x));
}
```

Is this is the anonymous function?

what is the name of this function ?

I tried to change **"Invoke"** with **"func"** but there is no syntax error but run-time error Occurred.

Is it Possible to have multiple methods with "Invoke" name and receiving different parameters In a single  view component class.

I Know that view component use to render partial views for this we use helper which is this

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("Here is the name of your view component")
```

**"component.InvokeAsynk"** Goes to your component class and finds The Invoke method and then follows this method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Invoke` and `InvokeAsync` methods on a `ViewComponent` are the methods that define the logic of the view component.  These are not anonymous functions.  They are regular c# methods that simply have the names `Invoke` and `InvokeAsync`.

You don't need to define both of them in your view component.
On the contrary you can only define one method.

Let us say you named it `Invoke` and then you rename it to `func` then you have changed the name of the method:

- you won't get a compiler error, but
- a runtime error will occur.

This is because the Asp.Net Core framework code that calls your view component expects it to have either a `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync` method and your `ViewComponent` now has neither.

You can name your view component anything you like but the name of the method which gets called to invoke it must be called `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync`.

A `ViewComponent` can only have one `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync` method.  A `ViewComponent` can't have both and it can't multiples of either one (with different parameters).  Attempting to do so will produce the following runtime error:

> View component 'ViewComponents.NameOfComponent' must have exactly one public method named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke'.

Comment: Sir Its Seems good you answering. And I am also willing that you answered it. I understand it. but whats I have to do to change the name

Comment: One thing more sir would you like to share your skyp Id or some other source to contact you if i have some confusion.
because before posting the question I try to find you on **stack overflow chat room ** but didn't succeeded

Comment: I updated my answer to answer that.  Questions should be via stackoverflow not skype so that the stackoverflow community gets the benefit of the question and answer.

Comment: sir I Know that i can change the name of my view component
But what i have to do to Write multiple Invoke methods.
suppose If i want to Write 2 Invoke methods

Comment: sir I Know that i can change the name of my view component
But what i have to do to Write multiple Invoke methods.
suppose If i want to Write 2 Invoke methods
1 is Invoke(){} 
2 is Invoke(string filter)
is it possible ?
OK if I want to notify You to please answer this question  then how I notify You

Comment: Updated my answer to answer that too.

Comment: Ahmad,  which part is still confusing?  I'm happy to provide more explanation. These things can sometimes be challenging to understand.